# Docker Dependency/Common Layer

Tags: docker, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, aws-lambda-layers

My company is migrating from AWS to GCP and I am tasked with making some very basic POCs. However, we currently have 4 Spring Boot Lambdas each with the same common dependency Lambda Layer and we are moving to  Google Kubernetes Engine.

I am completely new to Docker, Kubernetes, and GCP, so I might be missing some obvious stuff, but I appreciate the help!

Specifically, I'm finding it difficult to get the dep layer to work right. What I am trying to do (and it may not be the right approach) is to build the dep-layer with Docker and then use the .jar in that Docker image as a dependency in the builds of all the other APIs.

---

## Issue

If I mvn clean install the dep-layer and place the .jar in the class path of the test-app, I can run the Spring Boot app and everything works via postman

But, from what I understand of the docker files, I am building the jar and placing the image in docker desktop, then referencing the jar when building the test-app. However, when I run the Dockerfile of the test-app, mvn install fails with: `Could not find artifact com.dep:dependency-layer:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

#### dep-layer Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8 AS dependency-build
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven
RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

#### dep layer pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dep</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-layer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DependencyLayer</name>
    <description>Dependency Layer POC</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>26.15.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Ran this with `docker build -t deplayer .`

#### test-app Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8 AS main-build
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
COPY --from=deplayer /app/target/dependency-layer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven
RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests    ##Fails here
RUN mv /app/target/*.jar /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/app.jar"]
```

#### test-app pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.other</groupId>
    <artifactId>mcTesty</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mcTesty</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>com.other.mcTesty.McTestyApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dep</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-layer</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.other.mcTesty.McTestyApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

### Questions:

Does anyone see some obvious things I am missing? like maybe that I need a shade build for the dep-layer? Does Kubernetes/GKE even use layers? I see multi stage builds are a thing, should I have a docker file outside both apps the build and layer both? Something else?

---

### Clarifications

The test-app has the dep-layer as a dependency in it's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dep</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-layer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   
</dependency>
```

So, when building the test-app, I am trying to get Docker to see that jar I created and use it in the build of the test-app

Answer (score 0):

your question is slightly confusing.

Kubernetes is for orchestrating your infrastructure and services - think of it as infrastructure as code.

Dockerfiles are used to define and build docker images. Images can then be used to initialise a container that can be run.

So if you build an image, all you have is an image. If you run an image, you get a container with whatever was specified in the image as the contents within the container - all the app files, etc.

In the first instance, your dockerfile copies the contents of the project to the `/app` dir. This contains the pom.xml file that mvn requires.

In the second example where you have :

```
COPY --from=deplayer /app/target/dependency-layer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven
RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests    ##Fails here
```

At no point was the pom.xml or sourcecode copied to the image as part of the Dockerfile specification. In fact as you've copied the jar, it should have the dependency jars within it, and you should be able to just run it as it is. Try removing `RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests    ##Fails here` entirely and it may work, or give you another more useful error.

EDIT:
I've created a minimal reproducible example (I think) and I can see an obvious problem in that you've copied the jar to the output dir. This won't be where maven looks for the jar. When you run `maven clean install` the jar is output to the `target/` dir but also then appears under the local maven repository located under `~/.m2/`. Your jar will then be accessible by maven from there - so in your example `~/.m2/com/dep/dependency-layer/...`. So to get maven in your `test-app` `Dockerfile` to pick up the newly generated jar you need to install maven, and *then* `COPY` the relevant jar from your local `~/.m2` to the docker image's `~/.m2` dir. Then the jar will be available in the local maven repository.

Comment: My question is confusing because I am confused! haha. Basically  with both Dockerfiles, I need to just mkdir -> COPY -> mvn clean install. However, dpendency-layer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is a dependency declared in the pom.xml of the second one (test-app). So, I'm trying to get Docker to find the image built with the first one (dep-layer). Does that make more sense?

Comment: I've added an EDIT at the bottom of my above post that I think should resolve your issue. Give it a try and provide any feedback. I tried creating a minimal reproducible example and it looks like you're just using the target dir to copy the jar to which isn't where maven will look for the dependency.

Comment: Thanks, but the ~/.m2 is in my personal computer, ultimately need this to build as part of a pipeline (of some sort? I'm not the devops person on team...) is there a way to make the Dockerfile look for the jar in the target folder of an image that is already built?

Comment: yes the m2 dir is on your local machine, so you can either mount the dir to the same location in your docker container when you run it, or create the dir in the image and copy your jar into it. If you want to copy it across you'll have to create the dir structure and then copy the jar into the relevant dir, then maven will be able to find the dependency in the repository. Docker can't find the file for maven, thats not what docker is for. Docker is for creating an image and running the image as a container.